# "Greener pastures" and "pâturages plus verts"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> He worked there for two years before leaving for greener pastures.
>
> He decided it was time to move on to greener pastures.

"Greener pastures" is an idiom meaning a new better, more interesting activity, job and place. [Here it implies a better, more prosperous job.]

Does the literal translation "pâturages plus verts" convey the same meaning in French? Can one use it speaking about its new job? In which context can he or she use it?

[I know the signification of [verts pâturages]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/verts_p%C3%A2turages)

Comment: Although a nice word, _pâturage_ really sounds _vieille France_, _pré_  or _prairie_ is more commonly used nowadays.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε *Vert pâturages* seems to be common in Québec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il existe une expression *L'herbe est plus verte ailleurs* pour signifier que l'on pense que la situation est meilleure ailleurs.

On pourrait utiliser ici :

> Il est parti vérifier si l'herbe est plus verte ailleurs

ou

> Il est parti là où l'herbe est plus verte

Comment: On dit aussi souvent _L'herbe est toujours plus verte ailleurs_, pour pointer à la nature envieuse de l'être humain, qui aura tendance à croire, parfois à tort, qu'il la trouvera meilleur dans le pré du voisin.

Comment: Je connais plutôt l'expression *l'herbe est toujours plus verte chez le voisin*.

Comment: On est d'accord que l'expression de base est, comme le dit Benoit, "l'herbe est toujours plus verte ailleurs" pour pointer la nature envieuse de l'être humain. Je trouve que le détournement proposé par Damien est pas mal et sera très compréhensible pour un francophone qui ne connait pas l'expression anglaise. Expression anglaise qui, elle, est positive, au sens: "très bien pour lui", sans jugement. Pas sans contexte en tout cas.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's not an idiom in French, it would be understood the exact same way. As far as I know, we don't have an equivalent in French, the closer thing is "aller vers des cieux plus cléments" but it doesn't mean "better opportunities", it means something like "less hassle".